# Use Imager plugin with Element API?

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, plugin-imager

I'm trying to use the [Imager-Craft](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) plugin to make specific image transformations, but cannot figure out how to access Imager within the `element-api.php` file.

Imager shows plenty of template examples, but I'm not sure how to translate template code like this into straight Element API php.

````
{% set image = craft.assets().one() %}
{% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { width: 1000 }) %}
<img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}">```
````

Specifically, I'm trying to access that `craft.imager.transformImage` function.

Is this possible?

Comment: I see people using `craft()->plugins->getPlugin('Imager')`, but this doesn't seem to work in Craft 3 with Element API v2. I there a v2 equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In yii2 every instance of a module is stored in a public static property of the main class.

If the plugin is called image you can grab it via

```
Imager::getInstance()
```

This instance contains all the required components. The imager plugin it has 3 [components](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft/blob/craft3/src/Imager.php#L108)

```
$this->setComponents([
    'imager' => ImagerService::class,
    'placeholder' => PlaceholderService::class,
    'color' => ImagerColorService::class,
]);
```

You can access those via `Imager::getInstance()->imager` or `placeholder` or `color` in this case the instance of the plugin is also stored in a static `$plugin` variable. You can call

```
Imager::$plugin->imager
```

as well. You can see a working example [here](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft/blob/craft3/src/variables/ImagerVariable.php#L307)

```
use aelvan\imager\Imager as Plugin;
.... 
return Plugin::$plugin->imager->isAnimated($asset);
```

[This](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft/blob/craft3/src/variables/ImagerVariable.php#L35) is the function that is being called when you do `craft.imager.transform` -> the PHP equivalent what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a working solution, but really not sure if this is the best way use a plugin in the Element API.

```
'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

    $imager = new aelvan\imager\services\ImagerService();
    $image  = $entry->image->one();

    $resizedImage = $imager->transformImage($image, [
        'width' => 100
    ]);

    return [
        'image' => $resizedImage->url
    ];
},
```